# Random forest-the number of classifier

Tags: python, random-forest

I have a question about the RandomForest classifier.
I wonder if the number of decision trees is equal to the number of the classifier?
If not,what does the classifier really mean then?

Comment: Can you be more specific? What do you mean by "classifier" or "number of classifier"? Can you explain using attribute names?

Comment: For example,I was asked to train 10 classifiers with varying amounts of decision trees.I don't know what is the meaning of 10 classifiers here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One `RandomForestClassifier` object is a single classifier. Within that classifier, you have a number of decision trees, referred to as "estimators". You can find those in the `estimators_` attribute of the `RandomForestClassifier`. You're being asked to train 10 different `RandomForestClassifier`, each one with a different number of decision trees. For example:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
classifiers = [RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=num) for num in (8, 16, 32)]
```

That code would create (but not train) a list with three classifiers, containing different numbers of estimators (decision trees). Specifically, it would create classifiers with 8, 16, and 32 decision trees.